# How to print star pattern in this format * ** *** *** ***?

Tags: java, for-loop

How will i get output like this?

```
*
**
***
***
***
```

using on for loop;

```
public class Star {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        for(int i=1;i<=5;++i) { 
            for(int j=1;j<=i-1;++j) { 
                System.out.print("*"); 
            } 
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: What is your expected output for given inputs?

Comment: *
  **
  ***
  ***
  ***

Comment: Never put more information into comments, update your question instead. And for the future: read and apply [mcve] please!

Comment: Do you want to print 3 stars for numbers which greater than 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by using `if(i<2)` print pattern according to increment or else print constant format output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        if (i < 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
        } else {

            System.out.print("***");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Or `for (int j = 0; j < max(i, 3); j++) print("*")`.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i, j;
int n = 5;

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

        System.out.print("* ");

    }
    
    
    System.out.println();
}
```